# Is it possible to have one FunctionKey to access all my Azure functions? (C#)

Tags: xamarin.forms, azure-functions

New to Azure functions so bear with me. Let me get to the point.

1. All my functions will have `AuthorisationLevel=Function`
2. The function key will be read the from the keyvault (no hardcoding)

I am planning to have 20-30 Azure functions for my app - is it possible to have a single key for all of them?

Otherwise for each of them I have to make a call to get the key from the vault?

What is the suggested/best practice?

Many thanks

Comment: You could add same function key to all functions in the manage module.

Comment: I saw that "Add New function key" is this how people do it? if so that is fine.Can I ask you something basic here?  A Function App can have many "functions" Correct? so If I have 20 methods and each one is a function I only need 01 key correct?

Comment: oh I think what I stated above is wrong if I have a fuctionapp and I have many functions inside still i need a key for each correct?

Comment: Yes, cause your AuthorisationLevel=Function, so have to use the function key to access function, more detail you could refer to here.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-http-webhook-trigger?tabs=csharp#authorization-scopes-function-level

Comment: thanks for the link I missed that one,If I understand it correctly what I need is the "HostKey" that can be used for all functions in the function app.Correct? now is to understand the difference between master vs default and looks to me that default is the one to choose but I m maybe wrong . Learning.. thanks for you time

Comment: If you don't mind the level you could use, their values are same. Glad this could help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it.

After deploy, go to manage of your function app, then revoke the function key you are using now and add a new one as you want. Don't forget to save the edit.

[image]